# Why is the private signing key in lib sodium 64 bytes?

Tags: libsodium

To generate a keypair for signing in libsodium one can use (copied from documentation):

```
unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
unsigned char sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
crypto_sign_keypair(pk, sk);
```

`crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES` resolves to `crypto_sign_ed25519_SECRETKEYBYTES` and the latter resolves to `(32U + 32U)`.

When searching the internet for *ed25519 private key length*, it appears that the length should be 32 bytes.

Where does this discrepancy come from?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the public key is attached to the private key.

For example the following code (using lazysodium in Kotlin):

```
    val ls = LazySodiumJava(SodiumJava())
    val keypair = ls.cryptoSignKeypair()

    println("pub: ${keypair.publicKey.asHexString}")
    println("pri: ${keypair.secretKey.asHexString}")
```

gives:

```
pub: 23C26D24834E1B83D529AB907AB1C85CE8FCAA91627E9FD189CBBF86DD390BBF
pri: 3914ECBF9E52F85DB05394D668B8E0D50B0F6424FAB80E182EBF481CE4FC4D3D23C26D24834E1B83D529AB907AB1C85CE8FCAA91627E9FD189CBBF86DD390BBF
```

The second part of the private key is exactly the public key.

Comment: Thanks! But it's still unclear why this is the case and why there is no lib support for extracting only the privateKey.

Also see: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/why-are-nacl-secret-keys-64-bytes-for-signing-but-32-bytes-for-box